# Latex Beamer multiple columns

Tags: beamer, columns

So Im doing this presentation with Latex Beamer powerpoint. I have one slide that looks like a mess, but I need the equations in columns and in one slide. Heres how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of the slide]

And this is the code used:

```
\begin{frame}{Introducing bootstrap}
- Historical data Z to a risk estimate $\hat{\Psi}$ \\
\begin{columns}[c]
\column{0in}
$\theta \rightarrow Z$,\\
the real world

\column{0in}
$\hat{\theta}=g(Z)$\\
$\hat{\Psi}=\Psi(\hat{\theta})$\\
estimation

\column{0in}
and

\column{0in}
$\hat{\theta} \rightarrow \hat{Z}^{*}$\\
in the computer

\column{0in}
$\hat{\theta}^{*}=g(\hat{Z}^{*})$\\
$\hat{\Psi}^{*}=\Psi(\hat{\theta}^{*})$\\
estimation
\end{columns}

- The idea is to identify the distribution of $\hat{\Psi}^{*}$ given $\hat{\theta}$ with that of $\hat{\Psi}$ given $\theta$.
\end{frame}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this look ordered and nice?

Thanks

Comment: Why zero-width columns? What if you set the width to e.g. `0.2\linewidth`?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the options `t` (top alignment) and `onlytextwidth` when initiating the `columns` environment, and you could provide more-normal widths than `0in` for the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introducing bootstrap}

- Historical data Z to a risk estimate $\hat{\Psi}$ 

\medskip
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.2\textwidth}
$\theta \rightarrow Z$,\\
the real world

\column{.2\textwidth}
$\hat{\theta}=g(Z)$\\
$\hat{\Psi}=\Psi(\hat{\theta})$\\
estimation

\column{.1\textwidth}
and

\column{.2\textwidth}
$\hat{\theta} \rightarrow \hat{Z}^{*}$\\
in the computer

\column{.2\textwidth}
$\hat{\theta}^{*}=g(\hat{Z}^{*})$\\
$\hat{\Psi}^{*}=\Psi(\hat{\theta}^{*})$\\
estimation
\end{columns}

\bigskip
- The idea is to identify the distribution of $\hat{\Psi}^{*}$ given $\hat{\theta}$ with that of $\hat{\Psi}$ given $\theta$.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```